# HTML CSS Making the background image static

Tags: html, css, image, background

I'd like to make it so the background image stays in the same place (static) while the website scrolls up and down. How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`background-attachment: fixed;` should do it i believe.

Comment: Note that this won't work correctly with IE6, in case that matters to you.

Comment: @Corey: Only if applying to an element other than `body` or `html`... But i suppose that could be the case here.

Comment: Hmm, I seem to remember having issues even on a `body` tag... but the point is, stop using IE6.